# Flutter Firebase Unsopported class loader

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an app using Flutter and Firebase. I have part of the code working, which is

```
 final collection = Firestore.instance.collection('regions').orderBy('region_id');
 collection.getDocuments().then((data){
     print(data);
   })
 .catchError((e){print(e);});
```

After that I am getting

```
W/.example.herme(13551): Unsupported class loader
I/.example.herme(13551): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/.example.herme(13551): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
W/.example.herme(13551): Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
I/.example.herme(13551): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
W/.example.herme(13551): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String; (light greylist, reflection)
```

and so on, in the firebase firestore I have a collection called regions which has 16 documents on it and every document has a collection inside called comune with documents on it.

What does that error mean? Has it got to do with the collection?

Comment: Did you ever find out what was causing this message?

Comment: yes. Apparently that function is not for flutter. I am using a dart archive called query with functions like that but when calling them is just return Firestore.instance.collection('x').getDocuments; So I have Query.getdoc('x').then((data){}); and it si working fine now

Answer (score 0):

The initial cause of this issue is that you're using an outdated function on Flutter [cloud_firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore). Currently you can fetch all the documents inside the collection with `Query.get()` - where Query contains the Firestore Collection Query.

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('regions')
    .orderBy('region_id')
    .get()
    .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
      snapshot.docs.forEach((QueryDocumentSnapshot element) {
        /// call element.data() for the DocumentSnapshot
        debugPrint('getDocuments id: ${element.id} data: ${element.data()}');
      }
    });
```